# GDB Attempt to take address of value not located in memory

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, memory-address

I have the following if statements (c++) that are supposed to create a false conditionreturn a proper value:

```
(gdb) print (start0 < board.size() && start1 < board[0].size() - ship.GetSize() && ori=='h')
$7 = false
(gdb) print (start0 < board.size() && start1 < board[0].size() && ori=='n')
$8 = true
```

but when I try to test for two of the these values I get the following error:

```
(gdb) print (start0 < board.size() && start1 < board[0].size() - ship.GetSize() && ori=='h') || (start0 < board.size() && start1 < board[0].size() && ori=='n')
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

This results in the entire if statement they are in failing to pass. I'm 100% certain the values are correct after extensive testing, am I just missing something? This is the if statement the code is in:

```
if ((start0 < board.size() - ship.GetSize() && start1 < board[0].size() && ori=='v') ||
    (start0 < board.size() && start1 < board[0].size() - ship.GetSize() && ori=='h') ||
    (start0 < board.size() && start1 < board[0].size() && ori=='n')){
```

Comment: Have you tried putting another set of brackets round the expression?

Comment: Yes, to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, that is the end of my guesses, without a reproducable example.

Comment: This looks like a bug in GDB. You should try using latest GDB, and if the problem still reproduces, create a small example and file a bug in GDB bugzilla.